# What's best way to find closest values of datetime in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
date1 = ['2020-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2017-01-01']
date2 = ['2020-03-01', '2021-01-01', '2018-01-02']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'], index=date1)
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['col1'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(date2)
df2['col2'] = np.zeros(3)
for ind in df2.index:
    val = df2['col1'][ind]
    df2['col2'][ind] = df1.iloc[df1.index.get_loc(df2['date'][ind], method='nearest')][val]
```

I need assign df2['col2'] value from df1 column = df1['col1'] and index closest to value in df2['date']
I found way to do it with itteration through dataframes, but i have big one and need more efficient way.

Comment: for reference, what dimensions are we talking about, what is "more efficient"?

Comment: faster. Now I can assign 1 number at 1.7 seconds. It's unsatisfactory now. I think, there is way to avoid iteration or get_loc.

Comment: from your code example, it seems you're calling `get_loc` many times, so keep in mind that this adds complexity. the only thing I'd imagine to be faster compared to `get_loc` would be to work with all integers (nanoseconds since the epoch) instead of datetime to reduce the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

My friend helped me)
merge_asof https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html
is what I needed.